# Need to reinstall Ubuntu 12.04, but my computer doesn't recognize my USB startup disk. (Dual boot)

Tags: dual-boot

I need to do a clean reinstall of 12.04 OS.  I don't have a CD drive, and have created a USB startup flash drive.  I am running dual boot Windows 7, and Ubuntu 12.04.  The BIOS is booting from removable, but it does not seem to recognize the thumb drive, it goes straight to the GRUB menu. Am I doing something wrong?  Is there another way?

Comment: Booting from USB is something that is machine and BIOS specific, so you should give us the details of your machine.  You should find specifics about USB booting in your machine manual under BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

check to see if there is legacy usb support in bios. you may need to enable that to boot from the flash drive.  Also  escape or f12 f11 depending on the system board often brings up the boot menu where you can manually select what to boot from. Select it there and see if that lets you boot to the flash drive. If that doesn't work see if another device will boot from it or load vmware player and see if it boots from the flash drive to verify it was properly created.